# Agent Page Updates - Cannot Use Script Tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, widget, embed

I have an instagram widget that has been embeded into a profile page, but a new update on the backend has dictated that we are unable to use the < script > tag moving forward. How can I get this coding to pull in the widget without using that tag on the final line?

Thank you!

```
<blockquote class=“instagram-media” data-instgrm-permalink=“https://www.instagram.com/sunnydardengroup/”>
<a href=“https://www.instagram.com/p/B9Qf8QWh5zB/” target=“_blank”></a>
</blockquote>
<script async=“” src=“//www.instagram.com/embed.js”></script>
```

I tried several changes, all with no success.